# Get value from combobox and add a number to it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the "value" from a combo box and simply add one to it. I think I need to convert it to a integer but can't make parse work either. Next I want to put that new number into a text box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetNextCategoryNum(sel)
    {
        var NextNumber; 
        var number = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
        NextNumber = number ++1;
        alert("Last number used "  + number );
        textbox = NextNumber 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Need to have textbox with value code does not work.   function GetNextCategoryNum(sel)
   
   {
          
          var NextNumber; 
          var textbox = document.getElementById("txtCatalogID");
             var number = parseInt(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value); 
          NextNumber = number + 1;
          alert("Last number used "  + NextNumber );
          document.getElementById("txtCatalogID")          
   }

Answer (score 1):

Three mistakes in your code:
1. value will return a string. So you need to change it to an integer.
2. "number ++1" is wierd. What you need is ++number. If you do not want to increase "number" but "NextNumber", then just put on number + 1.
3. What is "textbox"? if it refers to a textbox object then you need declaring it.

So what I suggest is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetNextCategoryNum(sel)
    {
        var NextNumber; 
        var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
        var number = parseInt(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value); 
        NextNumber = number + 1;
        alert("Last number used "  + number );
        textbox.value = NextNumber;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok Nextnumber has a  number plus one, but the textbox is still blank, the name of the textbox is actually is txtCatalogID and its on a form called myform.  <form Name="myForm" method="POST" action="<%=webpagename%>">
  CatalogID <input type="text" name="txtCatalogID" size="12"></p>

Comment: better give your textbox an id: <input type="text" id="txtCatalogID" name="txtCatalogID" size="12" /> then use: var textbox = document.getElementById("txtCatalogID"); to get the reference of that object. The rest of the code should be fine.